# Division using cross vector

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, solution-verification, cross-product

Given $4$ vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, $\vec c$, $\vec d$, if

$$\vec u=\vec a \times \vec b= \hat n \ ab \sin θ \tag 1$$
where $\hat n$ is a normal unit vector of both $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, and $θ$ is the angle formed by the two vectors. Same for $\vec u$. I have
$$\vec v=\vec c \times \vec d= (-\hat n) \ cd \sin θ' \tag 2$$

If I consider

$$\frac{\vec u}{\vec v}=\frac{\hat n \ ab \sin θ}{-\hat n \ cd \sin θ'}=\frac{\hat n \ ab \sin θ}{-\hat n \ ab \sin θ'}$$

Is it correct this appoach?

$$\frac{\vec u}{\vec v}=\frac{\color{red}{\not{\hat n}} \ ab \sin θ}{-\color{red}{\not{\hat n}}\ cd \sin θ'}=k \frac{\sin θ}{\sin θ'}, \quad k=-ab/cd \tag 3$$

the value of the $(1)$ is different for different values of $θ$ (and $θ'$) and therefore the division $(3)$ not uniquely determined? Is it correct?

Comment: Well, $\theta$ is uniquely determined by $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. | By the way, are you assuming $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ lie in the same plane as $\vec{c},\vec{d}$ but oppositely oriented? You don't explicitly state this assumption, but then you use the same normal vector $\hat{n}$ for both $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}\times\vec{d}$ which would require this assumption. | There isn't really a division operation for vectors, but if $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are parallel there is a unique scalar $\lambda$ for which $\vec{v}=\lambda\vec{u}$ of course.

Comment: @runway44 It is not necessary. $\vec a, \vec b$ lie in the plane $\pi \parallel \pi'$ where $\vec c, \vec d$ lie. After od course Yes, naturally I will must use the same normal. Yeah, isn't really a division but the division between vectors not exist.

Comment: (Obviously I am talking about vectors emanating from the origin, in which case parallel planes containing them are just the same plane.) So, what really is your question? Your formula for $\lambda$, the constant of proportionality between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, is of course correct.

Comment: @runway44 I will glad to have your answer (or other answers) also to have a drawing justifying better my knowledges: "is different for different values of $θ$ and is therefore not uniquely determined." considering the ratio of two $\sin$.

Comment: They're different $\hat{n}$s.

Comment: @J.G. I'm happy to have also your answer if it possible on different $\hat n$(s). Otherwise I don't really understand or I have written something senseless in my question. Thank you for your comprehension.

Comment: @Basco But I have cancel $\hat n$. However can you edit your answer and can you delete your comment putting them into your answer? Otherwise I get confused. I often don't read the comments to reconstruct everything. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As J.G. mentioned in the comments, your definition of division isn't very general because the only way the $\vec n$'s are the same (and thus cancellable) is if all of the vectors are in the same plane.  And I suspect it's not well-defined even that context either.

---

But if you're interested in division of vectors, you should look into *Geometric Algebra*.  There is a new vector product $\vec u\vec v$ called the geometric product which has the property
$$\vec u\vec v = \vec u\cdot \vec v + \vec u \wedge \vec v$$
That $\vec u\wedge \vec v$ is probably unfamiliar to you as well, but roughly it's a different (and more general) way to think about the cross product.  It's not exactly the same though.  But anyway, because $\vec v\wedge\vec v = 0$ for all $\vec v$, we can define the inverse of a vector $\vec v$ as
$$\vec v^{\ -1} = \frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|^2}$$

This works because
$$\begin{align}
\vec v\vec v^{\ -1} &= \vec v\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|^2} \\
&= \frac{\vec v\vec v}{\|\vec v\|^2} \\
&= \frac{\vec v\cdot \vec v + \vec v\wedge \vec v}{\|\vec v\|^2} \\
&= \frac{\|\vec v\|^2 + 0}{\|\vec v\|^2} \\
&= 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribute that I have appreciated +1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no division of vectors in terms of the inverse of the cross  product.

Essentially, when using the cross product you get a vector, but contrary to real numbers where its division produces another number, such an operation does not seems to exist with vectors. For example, when using real numbers the division of a number by itself is one, but the closest thing we have with vectors is a normalization (where what it becomes unity is the length of the vector, but do not cancel the direction). In terms of products $a\: .\: 1=a$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}$, but there is not such a unit vector satisfying that property for the cross product, ergo the division it is not defined in the same sense.

Comment: Please can you explain better why there is not the division of vectors in terms of the inverse of the cross product? Thank you.

Comment: Consider your ratio $\bar{u}/\bar{v}$, for simplicity consider that the vectors are the same. The result it is a scalar, not a vector. If you can find a unit vector for the cross product satisfying $\bar{u} \times \bar{1}=\bar{u}$ for all $\bar{u}$ in the space under consideration, then it may be possible to get an inverse in the sense you are looking for. However, such an object does not seems to exist.